# Variable in image in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get something working in a game I'm making. Basically, I have a character selector:

```
<div id="CharacterChoose" style="display: none;">
<input id="TestChar1" type="button" value="Test Character 1"/>
<input id="TestChar2" type="button" value="Test Character 2"/>
</div>

<script>
    $("#StartButton").click(function () {
        $("#SplashScreen").hide();
        $("#CharacterChoose").show();
    });
    $("#TestChar1").click(function () {
        var selectedCharacterFirstName = "Character"
        var selectedCharacterLastName = "2"
        var selectedCharacter = "testchar1"
        $("#CharacterChoose").hide();
        $("#GameCanvas").show();
    });
    $("#TestChar2").click(function () {
        var selectedCharacterFirstName = "Character"
        var selectedCharacterLastName = "2"
        var selectedCharacter = "testchar2"
        $("#CharacterChoose").hide();
        $("#GameCanvas").show();
    });
</script>
```

However, in my Script.js file, I am trying to make the character's image change depending on what character was chosen. So technically, character1 would be taken as this:

```
var CharSrcRight = 'images/character/character_char1/char_stand';
```

But I tried:

```
var CharSrc = 'images/character/character_' + selectedCharacter + '/' + selectedCharacter + '_stand';
```

Any help?

PS: For some reason, my game will glitch if I try to put the script that I used in my html file into the script of my script.js file. Any advice?

Comment: what do you mean by glitch? What happens?

Comment: Nothing else will load when I try to click the character's button. It will stay on that screen.

Comment: What do you get in the developer console? Press F12 in your browser, then click on `Console` and post any messages here which have a Red X

Comment: The only error I get is "Unexpected string on line 1." Line 1 is the line with CharSrc on it. The same error will appear even if I have the code in the HTML document. Also, I made a mistake in my last comment. Unless the code is in the HTML document, it will not go past the first scene, where it asks you to press start.

Comment: Makes sense, you havent defined `selectedCharacted` before Line 1 but you are trying to use it.

Comment: When you put the script in your script.js file, what are the errors in the Console?

Comment: I'm telling you, I am not getting any that relate to putting it in the script.js. I know how to find errors using the Console, but for some reason they simply will not appear. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3 variables you have created are local to the click handler method in which they are declared. Since you are using `var` when declaring the variable.

Since you want to access the variable value in a method outside of current scope, you need to declare them in a shared scope so that both the methods can access the same copy. In your case since you are using 2 different script elements the shared scope is the global scope.

```
var selectedCharacterFirstName, selectedCharacterLastName, selectedCharacter;
$("#StartButton").click(function () {
    $("#SplashScreen").hide();
    $("#CharacterChoose").show();
});
$("#TestChar1").click(function () {
    selectedCharacterFirstName = "Character"
    selectedCharacterLastName = "2"
    selectedCharacter = "testchar1"
    $("#CharacterChoose").hide();
    $("#GameCanvas").show();
});
$("#TestChar2").click(function () {
    selectedCharacterFirstName = "Character"
    selectedCharacterLastName = "2"
    selectedCharacter = "testchar2"
    $("#CharacterChoose").hide();
    $("#GameCanvas").show();
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still won't work. I also can't figure out why the script part will only work in the HTML document.